# Bootstrap 3: Cant make two affix side bars

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently coding a bootstrap website, I am about to finish. but I have one part that I can't accomplish, and its the Side bar,

I have made a bootstrap 3 spy + affix side bar for example: 
http://s.bootply.com/render/RpfBuecywd

Imagine that the Side scrollspy menu has another menu after it, that will move when you scroll with you.

I am trying to do something like this: [image]

I am always failing to do that since everytime I create the 2nd menu the menu itself doesn't scroll and the page gets broken..
if any of you guys can help me do that, I will love you for ever. I am trying to do it for the past 30 minutes and I cant think of a way to do it.

Thanks,
Aviv.

Comment: Do you mean the scrollspy isn't working or the affix isn't working? Are you looking for something like this? http://www.bootply.com/TqufBjtPSZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fix for it, simply opening up a ul inside a ul
example:

```
<ul class="nav affix">
<li>Something</li>
<li>Something</lI>
<ul class="nav affix-top">
<li>Something 2</li>
<li>Something 2</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="sidebar-nav-fixed affix">
  <div class="well">
    <ul class="nav ">
      <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.well -->

  <div class="well">
    <ul class="nav ">
      <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.well -->
</div><!--/sidebar-nav-fixed -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Here's a similar example: [Right and Left Sidebars Fixed](http://www.bootply.com/101100)**

*Always include a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of you code when asking questions.*

Comment: Sadly, that's not what I wanted. I didnt want a left and right side bars, I wanted a Bar under a Bar , like this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/dbTbV.png but fixed with scrollspy

Comment: I did try it. the page broke. but I need a bar under a bar and not bar next to a bar :/ I will try again. wait. I think I did a mistake.

Comment: **EDIT: yup. it did not work. it did not scroll with me (scroll spy)**